# How to execute child method inside parent ExtJs(Sencha)

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6-classic

I have two controllers:

```
Ext.define('ParentController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.parent',
    sayHelloFromChild: function() {
      this.sayHello(); // Uncaught TypeError: this.sayHello() is not a function
    }
});

Ext.define('ChildController', {
    extend: 'ParentController',
    alias: 'controller.child',
    sayHello: function() {
      console.log('Hello);
    }
});
```

I want to call child method `sayHello();` inside parent controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just tested in sencha fiddle.

Look : https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2r1g

You have syntax error in `console.log('Hello);`. This is a problem.

Comment: Thank you, it is good example, but you attach child controller for window.
I want attach parent controller and to execute that method. It is possible?

Comment: Isn't possible because Parent Controller doesn't inherit the methods from the Childs.

Comment: Ah it is so bad. 
How I understand one way it is move my method in parent controller and reuse in child.

Comment: Not only, check out the mixins class https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/classic/Ext.Class.html#cfg-mixins